# Is there a difference between static_assert(std::is_default_constructible_v<X>) and DefaultConstructible concept?

Tags: c++, type-traits, c++-concepts

I'd like to declare a class template for which the template parameter needs a default constructor.  I can see two ways to do this, and I'm not sure if there's a difference between them or how to decide which to use.  There's the `DefaultConstructible` concept in Boost, which checks that a default constructor for a given type exists by simply trying to invoke it:

```
// from boost/concept_check.hpp
BOOST_concept(DefaultConstructible,(TT))
{
  BOOST_CONCEPT_USAGE(DefaultConstructible) {
    TT a;               // require default constructor
    ignore_unused_variable_warning(a);
  }
};
```

On the other hand I think I could also use `static_assert(std::is_default_constructible<T>)`.  Are these two approaches equivalent, and is there an advantage to either?

Comment: I don't know the boost concept but it looks like it's actually trying to default construct a `TT` and in that case, it does more than `is_default_constructible`:  _"`std::is_default_constructible<T>` does not test that `T x;` would compile; it attempts direct-initialization with an empty argument list (see `std::is_constructible`)."_

Comment: There's also std::default_initializable, if you can use it.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have much experience with the boost concepts, but one of key ideas of C++ concepts is that they are checked earlier in the compilation phases.

I.e. `static_assert` is checked after overload resolution, while concepts are checked at the template's instantiation time.